# How to save data as array in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I have some of the data, I want to save my data-id in array format. How can I do this? Below is my controller code.

Controller:

```php
public function PostSaveRentCertificateReport(Request $request)
{
    $report = $request->session()->get('report');
    $reports = new Report;
    $reports->column_one = $report->sum('column_one');
    $reports->column_two = $report->sum('column_two');

    // I want to save those id as array
    $reports->adc_report_id = array('$report->id');
    $reports->save();

    $notification = array(
        'message' => 'Report Created Successfully',
        'alert-type' => 'success'
    );

    return redirect()->route('adc.pending.reports')->with($notification);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can encode the data as JSON before saving it.

```php
$reports = new Report;
$reports->column_one = $report->sum('column_one');
$reports->column_two = $report->sum('column_two');
$reports->adc_report_id = json_encode([$report->id]);
$reports->save();
```

But this will make it a bit more difficult to work with.

Comment: Yes I was try your method but I can see now #attributes: array:1 [▼
    "adc_report_id" => ""[null]""
  ]

Comment: Is `$report->id` null?

Comment: Yes it shows that,

Comment: Then it's working as intended. You could add a check if you'd prefer an empty array. `json_encode($report->id ? [$report->id] : [])`

Comment: This should work, but i would take a look at casts on your model so you don't have to encode/decode all the time: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting